# Can I bind a function to the onscroll event of the parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, jquery-events

I have a page that does not load jQuery. An `<iframe>` included on that page (in the same domain) does load jQuery.

Using jQuery, is it possible to bind a function to an event of the `window` object of the parent page, even though it doesn't load jQuery?

Accessing the parent `window` doesn't seem to be a problem; this works (at least in Firefox 4):

```
console.log($(parent)); // displays "jQuery(Window index.html)" in the console
```

To give some context, I'm developing the document to be loaded within the `<iframe>`, but I don't control the parent page, so I can't use a solution that requires adding jQuery to it. Ultimately I want to subscribe to the `onscroll` event of the parent `window` to execute a function in the `<iframe>` every time that scrolling happens in the viewport.

I've tried (within the `<iframe>`):

```
function my_function() {
  console.log('Scrolling...');
}
$(parent).scroll(my_function);
```

However, that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a working example:

http://troy.onespot.com/static/stack_overflow/onscroll/parent.html

The document in the `<iframe>` is here:

http://troy.onespot.com/static/stack_overflow/onscroll/iframe.html

Comment: Both of your working demo links are broken.  Either fix them or remove them please.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
parent.onscroll = function() { ... };
```

---

**Update:**

Try this, it works for me:

```
$(parent.document).scroll(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do this with jQuery to take advantage of its namespaced event feature (http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). I'll need to bind and unbind the function at various points throughout the script, and jQuery will make this easier. What confuses me is that $(parent).scroll(my_function) seems like it should work, but for whatever reason, it doesn't. I'm hoping to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: @Bungle Well, does the browser report any error? If it doesn't work then the browsers should report some errors....

Comment: No errors (at least in Firefox 4) - here's a working example: http://troy.onespot.com/static/stack_overflow/onscroll/parent.html

Comment: @Bungle Try this: `$(parent.document).scroll(function() { ... });`. It works for me. I have no idea why `parent.document` works but just `parent` doesn't...

Comment: Thanks, Šime - I gave it a shot, but it appears to only work in WebKit and Mozilla browsers. No luck in Opera 11 or any version of Internet Explorer that I tested. I also posted this question in the jQuery forum (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-i-bind-a-function-to-the-onscroll-event-of-the-parent-window-from-an-iframe), but I haven't had any answers yet.

Comment: @Bungle It works for me in all browsers (IE9, FF4, Safari 5, Chrome 10 and Opera 11). My demo is here: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/iframe/ As you can see, you can bind handlers to the parent window's document object, body object and paragraph object. However, binding to the parent object directly does not work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, Šime - your demo works for me as well, but it's using the click() method rather than scroll(). I believe the reason that click() works and scroll() doesn't is because scroll() needs to be bound to the parent window, not the parent window's document, in IE and Opera.

Comment: @Bungle Binding the scroll() handler on the parent's document object works in IE9, FF4, Safari and Chrome. Opera 11 is the only browser for which it doesn't work. See here: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/iframe/

Comment: It doesn't work for IE 6-8, which unfortunately still represents a much larger portion of the audience for which I'm developing. I do sincerely appreciate your help and efforts, but this is for a major website so I need to find a solution that works across all A-grade browsers back to IE 6. At this point it's looking like I may need to fall back to a plain JavaScript implementation after all.

Comment: @Bungle This is an interesting issue. I'd love to know why binding event handlers to `$(parent)` doesn't work in any of the browsers. Consider starting a bounty if you don't get an answer by tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks again, Šime - I may just do that. I'm also wondering if this could be a jQuery bug or feature limitation, so I might submit a jQuery bug report just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to control a parent page which in another domain, so this is not possible for security reasons.

And you can find [many articles](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=iframe%20different&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iframe%20different%20domain) about this problem, If this is not your case tell us because sure there is another problem.

If in the same domain, what about using this:

<strike>$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(this).parent().scroll(function(){//stuff});
    });</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(window.parent.document).scroll(function(){//stuff});
});
```

Comment: Both windows are in the same domain. I updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks Amr, but that didn't work. I wouldn't expect the parent() method to work since it's designed for DOM traversal, not for accessing a parent window.

Comment: Thanks, Amr - that's the same approach that Šime arrived at, which works in WebKit and Mozilla browsers. IE and Opera seem to need the scroll() method called on the parent window, not the parent window's document.